# What are some important considerations when developing a DBaaS (DataBase as a Service)

Tags: design, database, cloud-computing

I'm interested in creating a Database as a Service.

I want users of the service to be able to do a few seemingly not very simple things.

Sign up and be given access to a JSON datastore that they can easily query from a RESTful API.

Now I've implemented RESTful account management with Eve in python, so a user can sign up and be granted access to a single global collection, with write access and read access to their own items.

Now the beauty / simplicity of Eve seems to be conflicting with my use-case, for `POST` / `PUT` to be enabled on an endpoint there needs to be a schema defined up front. To get around this I've just created a simple item with a string datatype that allows persistence of the entire JSON object.

But this means that the user would lose the ability to query for objects they've stored and would have to retrieve all their objects, parse them and then query them application side. Which doesn't seem much like a service users would want to adopt.

Comment: Hi Luke, it sounds like your question is about a JSON-store PaaS.  What makes your description as written, "*a database*"? ... "*A comprehensive collection of related data organized for convenient access, generally in a computer.*" [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/database)